Suggestions on ranking covariate time series
I have a multivariate time series problem where I need to predict a main time series given many potential covariates. I need to not only choose the best covariates for prediction but also determine if they have a high, medium, or low effect. It could obviously be the case that none have a very high effect. Another complication I have is that many of these covariate time series are full of 0s. Any suggestions on which papers to read/techniques to consider?
